# How to compose a jQuery selector for multiple descendants?

Tags: jquery

I need something like this:

```
$("#id > div, #id > div2").css(...);
```

I need to apply the same CSS attributes, using jQuery, to two different containers, both of which are children of the same parent But I don't know if it's possible. I tried it, but it's not working; any ideas?

```
$("#1403171021 > #playArrowAnimation").animate({marginLeft: "+=50%"}, 430, function(){ $('#playArrowAnimation').fadeOut(0, function(){ this.animation = 0; }) });
        $("#1403171021 > #playArrow","#1403171021 > #cap").css({'opacity':'0'});
```

That is the jquery code that must be aplied to the two child containers of the parent container with id 1403171021

I cant write the code so its like that:

```
<span id="1403171021">
```

//Two containers i want reach with jquery selector

```
<div id="n2">
</div>
</span>
```

Comment: what isn't working with this code?

Comment: Assuming the selectors are appropriate that approach will work, which implies your selectors are wrong. Can you show your [mcve] HTML so that we can see the elements you're trying to select?

Comment: Yes sure let me a minute its a long code so i take only the part i need

Comment: Please do remember the 'minimal' part of the guidance; we only need a representative sample, not the whole of your code.

Comment: Your selectors are wrong (otherwise what you posted should work); you need to show HTML.

Comment: I cant post the html code it says it is not properly written, ill try what mike said and give you an answer

Comment: @KevinAntolinezMiranda try creating a code snippet and post the HTML/CSS/JS in there (it's a button directly in the Stack Overflow interface when you edit your message, or create a new post)

Comment: So the html5 syntax is not the problem i checked it but i will change it anyway with a character before to avoid more possible problems

Answer (score 0):

Your ID's are incorrect (specifically `1403171021`).  Here are the conditions of valid IDs:

- [HTML4](https://www.w3.org/TR/html4/types.html#type-id): ID must start with a character

  > ID and NAME tokens must begin with a letter ([A-Za-z]) and may be followed by any number of letters, digits ([0-9]), hyphens ("-"), underscores ("_"), colons (":"), and periods (".").
- [HTML5](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#the-id-attribute): ID must contain at least one character

  > The value must be unique amongst all the IDs in the element's home subtree and must contain at least one character. The value must not contain any space characters.

---

To fix yours simply include a character.  Placing the character at the front is more widely supported between the different DocTypes.  One way to improve it:

- `1403171021` to `id-1403171021`